# Apache rewrite only domain name not the hostname

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I have the following:

```
http://test.inside/index.html?something=big
http://otherthing.inside/index.html?something=else
```

"test" and "otherthing" can be anything. I want to capture what ever was typed between http:// and the first period.

I want those to redirect to

```
http://test.correct-domain.com/index.html?something=big
http://otherthing.correct-domain.com/index.html?something=else
```

Is this even possible? I need to do this in the VirtualHost statement using RewriteRule.

Something like this but I also need to capture the first part between http:// and the first period.

```
RewriteRule ^/(.*)$ http://??.correct-domain.com/$1 [R,L]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes it is very much possible. You can use this code in your `DOCUMENT_ROOT/.htaccess` file:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^([^.]+)\.inside\. [NC]
RewriteRule ^ http://%1.correct-domain.com%{REQUEST_URI} [NE,R=301,L]
```

`%1` is the back-reference to first part in `HOST_NAME` being captured in `RewriteCond`.

Comment: @Jocker: This is linking to current question only.